# Ensure type of 'this' is identified correctly

Tags: typescript

If I have the code:

```js
const test = {
  a: 1,
  b() {
    const test = this.a; // works
    const test2 = this.c // fails
  }
}
```

Typescript is able to pickup on the type of this. If I use the same code in my codebase, however, I'm not getting any error at all, because the tpye of `this` at that point is `any`.

I've tried fixing this problem by changing config settings, but none seem to work. Can anyone help me find a way to have typescript properly identify the type of `this` is my code?

Comment: Check your `tsconfig.json`, find `compilerOptions`, and make sure you either use `"strict": true` or `"noImplicitThis": true`.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YG8BQMYEMBcMAjADRYwBGAFAJTpnaiSwJKpQAWAlhAHQ4DcMAPRCYAdxAAnANYR6MRkhZQATCjhdewYaIBmOTgBs52AL4ZTQA

Comment: @KarolMajewski That solves the problem, thanks - if you'd like to add an answer, I can accept it, I think it may be particularly useful with playground links (as you can turn off noImplicitThis in the playground and see the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you are coding in TypeScript, but that gets transpiled to JavaScript, and at runtime, JavaScript is executed.

Therefor, at runtime you loose the typing, which makes Typescript so wonderful.
And Javascript will now try to access the not existing `this.c` and if its not existing, create it on the fly. Therefor the value of the not existing `c` is now `undefined`.

At compile time you could minimize the problem by using a linter (like TSLint, or EsLint configured for Typescript) and ensure that variables have to be declared before usage (for TSLint, the rule is called "no-use-before-declare").
That should capture most cases.

For generic usages it gets more complicated.
You could do a check against `undefined`. But if you have cases where a variable may not be initialized and thats "okay", then you have to initialize it with `null`, so that you are able to distinguish "not existant" and "yep its there but not initialized".

hope that helps a bit

---

Update:
Sorry, it seems i misunderstood your question

Beside the Linter rules, some settings in the tsconfig should also help.
[noImplicitAny](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) - will enforce the use of typings.
[noUncheckedIndexedAccess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) - Will raise the bar for accessing per index

Comment: Sorry - I'm either misunderstanding your answer, or my question isn't quite clear enough. I want the errors on undefined properties of this, but my typescript is, for some reason, failing to pick them up

Comment: ah sorry, i updated my answer, please try the two mentioned tsconfig settings. The first one should do the trick, the second is helpful in more generic coding settings.